# How to detect the current site/frontend language within Javascript

Tags: javascript, language

I want to detect the current site/frontend language within Javascript. How can I do to register the language for use within?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662923/extract-lang-value-using-javascript you can use `document.documentElement.lang`